de Broglie wavelength and resolution of microscope
I read about electron microscopes and it's said that electrons have a smaller deBroglie wavelength than the wavelength of light and therefore, better spatial resolution (lambda/numerical aperture).
Suppose we can send larger objects instead of electrons, for e.g., human beings, then the associated de Broglie wavelength is way smaller than that associated with electrons. And therefore, in principle such a ''human microscope'' will have a better spatial resolution?

Spatial resolution will not be determined by de Broglie wavelength anymore, that is all. A human spatial extent is much larger than the de Broglie wavelength, so other resolution issues are raised.

could you please explain a bit more? Sorry I didn't quite follow

By the terms "electron microscope" we mean that we shoot electrons to the object from which they reflect back and then we try to make a picture out of the reflected electrons. if we think of shooting out a human instead, taking the size of human to be very small(of the electron) as the size/ radius of an object doesn't really affect the debroglie wavelength its the mass that does we find so yes the debroglie wavelength would be really small but the energy required to accelerate such electron like particle to speeds near the speed of light would be a lot, also the relativistic effects would come into play.
But remember this is under the assumption that you could fit a mass of the human in a particle of the size of an electron. It has got nothing to do with human or electron infact the resolution of a proton microscope would be way better than that of an electron microscope.

Just to note that He ion microscopes are a thing, and have good resolution.

ok thanks Amit. Makes more sense.

did i lack somewhere in my answer? why the downvote :( ?

don't know who downvoted, I cannot vote yet is what it says.
